# AES key wrap encryption

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need crypto-algorithm AES in key wrap mode. Is there some open-source library or implementation that could be helpful?

It is important, that it must be key wrap mode.

Comment: Are you referring to [RFC 3394](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3394.txt)? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BouncyCastle supports key wrapping in AES with the [`AESWrapEngine`](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/AESWrapEngine.html).

You can look at [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246280/492405) to see more examples of BouncyCastle. The only difference is you will specify the `AESWrapEngine` instead of the `AESEngine`.

Answer (score 10):

The standard [SunJCE provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider) offers an implementation of [RFC 3394](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3394.txt). Just use the algorithm [`AESWrap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher):

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AESWrap", "SunJCE");
c.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, secretKey);
byte[] result = c.wrap(someKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a library available named `Bouncy Castle` you can use that library for wrapping your data encryption key using AES algorithm in `WRAP_MODE` ,here below code snippet might help you.

```
public static byte[] wrapKey(SecretKey key, SecretKey keyToWrap) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AESKW", "BCFIPS");

        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, key);

        return cipher.wrap(keyToWrap);
    }

    public static SecretKey unwrapKey(SecretKey key, byte[] wrappedKey) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AESKW", "BCFIPS");

        cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, key);

        return (SecretKey) cipher.unwrap(wrappedKey, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
    }
```