# AES decrypt for j2me

Tags: encryption, encoding, java-me, aes, bouncycastle

I read on this link 
[AES Encryption/Decryption with Bouncycastle Example in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243650/aes-encryption-decryption-with-bouncycastle-example-in-j2me?rq=1)
 about how to encrypt a string using AES as supplied by Bouncy Castle. The encryption method code works fine but decryption doesn't work.

Can anyone suggest how I can decrypt the encrypted string?

I've used the following code to test:

```
import com.codename1.util.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;

/**
 *
 * @author SAMUEL
 */
public class Tester {
    static  String strEnc = "Hi This is my String";
    final static String strPassword = "password12345678";

    private static byte[] cipherData(PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher, byte[] data)throws Exception
{
    int minSize = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
    byte[] outBuf = new byte[minSize];
    int length1 = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, outBuf, 0);
    int length2 = cipher.doFinal(outBuf, length1);
    int actualLength = length1 + length2;
    byte[] result = new byte[actualLength];
    System.arraycopy(outBuf, 0, result, 0, result.length);
    return result; 
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipher, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception
{
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aes = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));
    CipherParameters ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
    aes.init(false, ivAndKey);
    return cipherData(aes, cipher);
}

private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plain, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception
{
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher  aes = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));
    CipherParameters ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
    aes.init(true, ivAndKey);
    return cipherData(aes, plain);
}


public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{

    byte[] enc= encrypt(strEnc.getBytes(),"password12345678".getBytes(), "password12345678".getBytes());
    String encrypted =   Base64.encode(enc);
    System.out.println("Encrypted is:"+encrypted);
    byte[] dec= decrypt(encrypted.getBytes(),"password12345678".getBytes() , "password12345678".getBytes());        
    System.out.println("Decrypted file is:"+dec);
 }
}
```

Output is:

```
Encrypted is:sw0SrUIKe0DmS7sRd9+XMgtYg+BUiAfiOsdMw/Lo2RA=
```

And the exception stacktrace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: last block incomplete in decryption
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.java:281)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Tester.cipherData(Tester.java:28)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Tester.decrypt(Tester.java:40)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Tester.main(Tester.java:57)
```

Comment: First of all, this question contains way too little information. Second, I wonder if you even read the comments below the answer you're pointing to.

Comment: it contains link to the main issue i am having.. i did and it works fine for crypting but i am having issues with decrypting that is why i am askin

Comment: Eh, *where* is your code again? If you can edit your question I'd be happy to retract my close vote (these votes are mainly given if we *cannot* answer the question, not so much if we don't want to answer the question).

Comment: i am new to this site so i tried posting my code but for unknown reasons , i couldnt. but here is my code on codenameone forum...   https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/codenameone-discussions/kx4P_k5-epw/au12EhysVtYJ

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting to base 64 decode the ciphertext before decryption. You should also create a new String from the decrypted bytes.

When encoding/decoding character strings, always specify the encoding explicitly, otherwise you will be using the platform default, which is not the same on each and every platform.

So use for instance `new String(dec, "UTF-8")` to recreate the plaintext, and specify `"UTF-8"` for each and every `new String()` and `toBytes()` method.

Comment: It displays: this is a byte array instance ( `[B` ) identified by `a62fc3`.

Comment: You can say thanks by accepting. I don't think we're related though, try and not use too popular language on SO, it doesn't help the readability nor the look of SO.

Comment: hi . this has worked and i could encrypt and decrypt but i noticed when i encrypt and decrypt a string using aes but i noticed the result is different from the usual standard aes encryption/decryption
eg on device :"hello" is "01Fvdltwa2VKVPCH3ueHAA==" but on standard aes "hello" is "0tUfc3Qwod0qw1kVaI8ksw==".

how can i resolve this please

Comment: Make sure that encoding, mode of operation, key bytes and IV bytes are identical. Note that for the same key, you should use different IV's - in effect then the ciphertext would *always* differ (otherwise you would leak information; you would be able to distinguish if you encrypted the (start of) the same plaintext twice).

Comment: it works fine on my device. the output on my device is different from the output on http://aesencryption.net.. that is the issue i am facing now because i want to exchange data with my server even when they use the same key but i cant do this since my server aes encryption/decryption isnt same with my device aes encryption/decryption... hope u understand what i mean???

Comment: Eh, no, unfortunately.

Comment: i mean when i encrypt and decrypt on my device. it works fine and i can see result but when i encrypt same string on aesencryption.net.. the encrypted result is different from my own.. and i dont know why it is different... eg when i encrypt on my device "hello" the result is "01Fvdltwa2VKVPCH3ueHAA==" but when i encrypt "hello" on aesencryption.net the result is "0tUfc3Qwod0qw1kVaI8ksw==".. these they are different .. why is my encrypted output on device different from aesencryption.net output? .. note: this is my encryption key"re5fdh3jxlow5ncc".. pls hw can i resolve this?