# codeone packages and saving your work

Tags: encryption, aes, codenameone, public-key-encryption

I am trying to develop an encryption and decryption app where user will input text and password and click on encrypt/ decrypt and the respective operation will be performed.

1). **The problem I am facing is how to include Java Packages like** :-

> import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;
>
> import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
>
> import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
>
> import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
>
> import javax.crypto.Cipher;

2) **The second thing I want to know is How to share that text (encrypted) through other apps if I place share button.**

3) ***I also want to save the text with extension as abc.myapp***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all packages are available in [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) see the [JavaDocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/) for what's available.

Encryption and decryption should be done via the Bouncy Castle [cn1lib](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html). You can see a sample of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197691/aes-cbc-padding-encryption-decryption-on-cross-platform-net-c-sharp-and-codena).

Codename One has a share button API and a share API that works with text and images.

The last question is a bit problematic. Mobile devices don't have a file system in the way desktop OS's have them. Every app runs in its own locked down environment and can't really access other files. I suggest rephrasing the question in more general terms explaining what you are trying to achieve ideally with examples of apps that already do that.

Comment: Like if u save a file it will be saved with extensin .myapp which can be opened through myapp only and not via any other app

Comment: Mobile devices don't have a file browser in the sense that desktops have them. You generally work by opening URI's e.g. https://www.codenameone.com/blog/can-execute.html