# Cross-platform-AES-encryption for J2ME Blackberry

Tags: encryption, blackberry, java-me, aes

I am looking for AES encryption library for blackberry 7. i got this link for android and ios https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption but i am not able to find out for j2me blackberry.Please can anyone who has done this type of library with blackberry or who has this library please  share it and it would be very helpfull for me .

thank you

Comment: can anyone tell me how to integrate this in j2me blackerry or is there any other alternative.

Comment: google for **bouncy castle** framework. And check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243650/aes-encryption-decryption-with-bouncycastle-example-in-j2me

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Blackberry's own net.rim.device.api.crypto package?

Comment: @alex: thank you for response.Yes you are right but as my application doing multiplatform app and others android and ios developers are completed with this library interation https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption but for bb7 this lib is not available.do you know how can we solve this

Comment: The library is just one class with a few methods, less than 300 lines including verbose comments, so it should be easy to write another implementation with exactly the same methods but using Blackberry crypto API instead of javax.crypto.

Comment: ya thats wat i am thinking about but if you have checked the java class from that library the code consists of j2se code where blackberry doesnt support and i tried using bouncy castle couple of times but failed to execute that and i didnt find any other alternative to implement the same as like in library.